# Automator SCRIPT NEED: Select part of name file, find file with containing name, then copy this in item in another folder

Tags: macos, finder, automator, copy-paste, file

I have 3 folder:

JPG folder: contains my modified JPG files, the name of file is (examples): DSC02996 20181027 201438 (LR).jpg

RAW folder: contains my RAW files, the name of file is (examples): DSC02996.RAW

DESTINATION folder: i want to copy here my RAW file.

I need a script that looks for the beginning of the name in the JPG folder, then looks for the file in the RAW folder and copies the result to the DESTINATION folder.

It's possible?

Thanks in advance.
Guido

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions.  If you're looking for help with a script, please [edit] your question to include the script that's giving you errors.  If you're looking for someone to write the script for you, you should add that request into your question.

Comment: Is there always a space character after the DSCnnn part in the JPEG name?

Comment: nohillside: yes!

Comment: To the close voter who selected "This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center." as the reason, this question is about Automator which is a default application in macOS... so, IMO this question is on topic however, the OP shows no research effort and why I wouldn't up vote the question but, I'm not going to vote to close it since there is a viable answer offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Automator, create a new Service and mount your workflow like this:

[image]

Save it and name as CopyRaw or something you like.

**Shell Script:**

`awk '{print $1}' <<< "${1##*/}"`

**Usage:**

Righ click the file you want and click on your service CopyRaw.

Comment: You really do not need both a **Run Shell Script** _action_ and a **Run AppleScript** _action_! Just use the following _compound command_, `awk '{print $1}' <<< "${1##*/}"` in the **Run Shell Script** _action_, delete the **Run AppleScript** _action_ and in the **Options** for the **Spotlight** _action_ check the **[√] Ignore this actions input** _check box_, so there is a disconnect between it and the previous action, the **Set Value of Variable** _action_ should not be directly connected to the next action, in this use case.

Comment: @user3439894 nice, I'm updating the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! Work fine but with "ignore this actions" input check box unchecked! **Thanks to all!**

Comment: can I do something to make it work with multiple files selections? or folder?

Comment: @GuidoWido you can create a Folder Action instead of a Service, so whenever you paste a file in that folder the workflow will run. Plz mark it as a right answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: @Guido Wido you commented, "Work fine but with "ignore this actions" input check box unchecked!", and while that is true in this case, it's not in every case however, and as a general rule unless the _value_ of a **Set Value of Variable** _action_ is being directly passed to the subsequent _action_ for its use too, as well as it been set, then the **[√] Ignore this actions input** _check box_ should always be checked with this particular action! Put it this way, one way is the right way of doing it, in this case checking it, and the other is the wrong way, in this case not checking it.